# Newbie to ruby and a little stuck with if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is most likely a dumb mistake however im a little stuck with setting some if conditions inside this

```
output = "<option value='#{user.id}' #{strDisabled} >if (user.company_name != "")#{user.company_name},&nbsp end if (user.name != "")#{user.name},&nbsp end if (user.email != "")#{user.email} end</option>".html_safe
```

It is just outputting the ruby code, i am most likely miles out but im on a project that uses ruby and i have not :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick refactor to make it easier to read the code.

```
output = "<option value='#{user.id}' #{strDisabled}>"
output << "#{user.company_name }, " if user.company_name.present?
output << "#{user.name}, " if user.name.present?
output << user.email if user.email.present?
output << "</option>"
output.html_safe
```

one more way to do it is

```
output = "<option value='#{user.id}' #{strDisabled}>"
output << ([user.company_name, user.name, user.email].reject(&:blank?) * ', ')
output << "</option>"
output.html_safe
```

the second line just selects which of the 3 strings is not blank and joins them with `,`

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) helper for generating HTML tags:

```
content_tag :option, value: user.id do
  output = []
  output << user.company_name unless user.company_name.blank?
  output << user.email unless user.email.blank?
  output.join(",&nbsp").html_safe
end
#=> "<option value=\"123\">user's company name,&nbsp;user's email</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each piece that is Ruby code into `#{}` not just variables.
I don't think so that putting if inside a string is a good/proper thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to reformat your code to approximate what it seems like you're trying to achieve:

```
output = "<option value='#{user.id}' #{strDisabled} >"
if (user.company_name != "")
  output << "#{user.company_name},&nbsp;" 
end 
if (user.name != "")
  output << "#{user.name},&nbsp;" 
end 
if (user.email != "")
  output << "#{user.email}"
end
output << "</option>"
output = output.html_safe
```

You were missing numerous string terminators and semicolons for the non-breaking space HTML escape codes.  But your major issue was that you were trying to do everything on the same line, and weren't ensuring your if/else constructs were

1. Outside the HTML string and
2. Properly formed.

Are you using an IDE, or are you attempting to do this in a text editor?  If the latter, I highly recommend you attempt to at least find one which will do syntax highlighting, as this will make the issues you were suffering from a lot more visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this :

```
output = "<option value='#{user.id} #{strDisabled}'> 
  #{user.company_name if !user.company_name.blank?},&nbsp; 
  #{user.name if !user.name.blank?},&nbsp; 
  #{user.email if !user.email.blank?}
</option>".html_safe
```